# Updating the HTTP session in a GWT service test with Arquillian

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, gwt-rpc, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to test an application protected by a certificate, hence I have a filter putting the certificate in the HTTP session in front of my servlet.

This is a GWT application, so I'm using [gwt-syncproxy](http://www.gdevelop.com/blog/2010/01/testing-gwt-rpc-services/) and Arquillian.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestLiveLoginService {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap
                .create(WebArchive.class, "launcher.war")
                .addPackages(true, "com.mycompany.launcher")
                .addAsResource("resources/logback.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource("resources/web.xml")
                .merge(ShrinkWrap
                        .create(ExplodedImporter.class, "resources.war")
                        .importDirectory("war/launcher")
                        .as(WebArchive.class));
    }

    private static LoginService rpcService;

    @Before
    @RunAsClient
    public void initClient() {
        rpcService = (LoginService) SyncProxy.newProxyInstance(
                LoginService.class, "http://localhost/launcher/", "login");
    }

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void testLogin1() throws ServerException {
        User result = rpcService.login(new User.Builder(
                "user", "password").build());
        assertTrue((result != null));
    }

}
```

My test `testLogin1()` is failing because the server code is looking for a certificate that would be in the session in a normal login flow.

Is it possible to update the HTTP session in a Arquillian test? 
In this case, I can easily in my `initClient()` method add a mock certificate in the session.